# Iframe и открытие в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript

Мы на сайте site.com. Нужно узнать, на каком сайте в iframe находиться он (его адрес и не находится ли в iframe он тоже. Тот сайт, если он вообще есть, информацию посылать не будет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно в консоли разработчика посмотреть. Можно поискать теги iframe.

Comment: @SwaD и как автоматически смотреть в консоль? Ручной вариант не подходит.

Comment: ты хочешь на site.com узнать куда его встроили? Ожидается что встраиваться будет на другой домен?

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (top === window) {
  console.log("Не в iframe")
} else try {
  console.log(top.location.href)
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Сайт не даёт прочитать свой адрес")
}
```

Comment: что такое переменная  top?

Comment: @Gelloiss, глобальная переменная браузера. Окно того сайта, который открыт в браузере. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Comment: И за что минус? ((